# OData connection to Microsoft Dynamics GP 2019 "This data isn't available because the associated table in the external data source can't be found"

Tags: odata

Attempting to set up an OData external data source to Dynamics Great Plains - confirmed I can connect via OData using MS Excel, so I believe that's right. When attempting to set this up in Salesforce as an external data source, validate-and-sync gives back this error when using OData 2.0:

`This data isn't available because the associated table in the external data source can't be found. Contact your administrator for help. Attempted query URL: https://my.endpoint.com/GPOData/GP2SF/$metadata`

And when using OData 4.0, the error is a bit different:

`Can't sync the schema metadata for your external system. Check that the schema metadata is valid. Error code: null`

The endpoint URL I've configured is this: `https://my.endpoint.com/GPOData/GP2SF/`. Fetching that document via a browser returns:

```
{
  "@odata.context":"https://my.endpoint.com/GPOData/GP2SF/$metadata","value":[
    {
      "name":"Test","kind":"EntitySet","url":"Test"
    }
  ]
}
```

And following that $metadata URL, which is the URL SF references in its first error, gives this:

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx" Version="4.0">
<edmx:DataServices>
<Schema xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm" Namespace="Microsoft.Dynamics.GP.OData.Provider.Generated.GP2SF.Models">
<EntityType Name="SFTest">
<Property Name="BillAccount" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
</EntityType>
<EntityContainer Name="Container">
<EntitySet Name="Test" EntityType="Microsoft.Dynamics.GP.OData.Provider.Generated.GP2SF.Models.SFTest"/>
</EntityContainer>
</Schema>
</edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

Aside from an odd transition from JSON to XML, this seems correct.

Anyone have any ideas on what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Heard back from Salesforce on what's wrong - the object I'm attempting to sync lacks a primary key. Once you have a PK defined, the $metadata response will have a section like this in it:

```
<Key>
<PropertyRef Name="MyPKField"/>
</Key>
```

And once that's there, the object validates-and-sync's fine.